# Maven uses different repos in Azure Pipelines than local

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mule, anypoint-exchange

I have a project that fails `mvn package` in Azure Pipelines even if the same branch builds successfully locally. The issue is a missing dependency.

Locally, Maven downloads the dependency from

- https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee

In Azure Pipelines it tries to download the dependency from

- https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases
- https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public

The dependency is `org.mule.connectors:mule-soap-engine:jar:1.6.11`, which does exist in Mulesoft Nexus EE repository, used locally, but doesn't exist in the public repositories used in Azure DevOps.

Both builds are using the same `pom.xml` (*same reflog*). Since Mulesoft Nexus EE is a private repository, I have credentials configured in my local `settings.xml` and I use `MavenAuthenticate@0` to refer to the service connections in Azure Pipelines. `MavenAuthenticate@0` seems to be working.

```
##[debug]mavenServiceConnections=4ff28bb5-a556-4220-9260-a1d89c8c7c6b
##[debug]4ff28bb5-a556-4220-9260-a1d89c8c7c6b=https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/
##[debug]4ff28bb5-a556-4220-9260-a1d89c8c7c6b exists true
##[debug]4ff28bb5-a556-4220-9260-a1d89c8c7c6b auth scheme = UsernamePassword
##[debug]4ff28bb5-a556-4220-9260-a1d89c8c7c6b data REPOSITORYID = MuleRepository
##[debug]Found username/password service connection for package source https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/
##[debug]Generating configs for 1 external repositories.
##[debug]Detected username/password credentials for 'https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/'
##[debug]Agent.Version=3.220.5
##[debug]set task variable: userM2SettingsXmlPath=/home/vsts/.m2/settings.xml
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.settaskvariable variable=userM2SettingsXmlPath;issecret=false;]/home/vsts/.m2/settings.xml
##[debug]Adding authentication to settings file /home/vsts/.m2/settings.xml.
##[debug]Agent.Version=3.220.5
##[debug]set task variable: backupUserM2SettingsFilePath=/home/vsts/.m2/_settings.xml
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.settaskvariable variable=backupUserM2SettingsFilePath;issecret=false;]/home/vsts/.m2/_settings.xml
##[debug]Writing new settings.xml with added authentication.
```

What I don't get is why Maven in Azure Pipelines is trying in different repositories, that aren't even mentioned in the `pom.xml` or `MavenAuthenticate@0`. I'm out of ideas on how to debug this.

Comment: My assumption is based on defined `settings.xml` in azure pipelines...

Answer (score 0):

When Maven can not find a dependency it will try to download it from other repositories in the build, because it doesn't know which one is the right one, if any. It also will try repositories in transitive dependencies poms.

Repositories that start with https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/ are not intended to be used by outside MuleSoft and should not be used in your projects. If it is in a transitive dependency you don't have control over that.

You are not sharing enough information to further troubleshoot the issue. If it is working locally maybe you have additional credentials in the settings.xml of the local build that allow it to access additional repositories, and those credentials are missing in the Azure build.